# Hide div if text string length is more than 3 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div placed over the other and I want it to disappear if the text inside it is longer than 3 characters. I have tried to do this with the code below but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(#top).text().length > 3) {
    $(this).addClass('hide')
    $(this) removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTml:

<div id="bottom" class="hide" Style="background-color: green;  width:398px; height:196px;">
  <div id="top" class="show" Style="background-color: blue; width:398px; height:196px;">
    <!-- PHP REQUEST THAT GIVES LATEST UPDATE GOES HERE. If text string is longer than 2 characters I want this to hide. -->textmorethan3characters
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of hiding try ellipsis

Comment: Note that you shouldn't include jquery twice on the same page, especially not two different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your code.

1. `$(#top)` needed to be replaced by `$("#top")` (see the quotes around).
2. There was a missing `.` before `removeClass` function.

Correcting the above, the major problem with your code was wrong use of `$(this)`. You thought that it would point to `#top`, but it didn't.

Correcting all of these, below is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#top").text().length > 3) {
    $("#top").removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTml:

<div id="bottom" class="hide" Style="background-color: green;  width:398px; height:196px;">
  <div id="top" class="show" Style="background-color: blue; width:398px; height:196px;">
    <!-- PHP REQUEST THAT GIVES LATEST UPDATE GOES HERE. If text string is longer than 2 characters I want this to hide. -->textmorethan3characters
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. For the purpose of clarification do you know why the 'this' didn't redirect to the div? I am new to all this and trying to figure out why it worked on other programming but not this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bevan7 -- `$(this)` is a just a jQuery wrapper for `this`, which actually defines the current context (usually the current function). Since `if` statement is not a function, the context will be the `document.ready` function, and hence, it doesn't work as you expected. You can try `console.log(this.nodeName)` in the `if` block to know where `this` actually points to.

Comment: Thanks for that. It certainly explains it. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#top").text().length > 3)
    $("#top").fadeOut(2000);
  else
     $("#top").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#top,#bottom{
width:398px; 
height:196px;
color:#fff;
}
#top{background-color: blue;}
#bottom{background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottom">
  <div id="top">sdadsdsad</div>
</div>
```